# Utilizar variables de archivos JS en Vue2

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, vue.js

Adquirí uno tema diseñado en Bootstrap 3 y quiero utilizarlo en un proyecto que tiene Vue2 como frontend. No tengo problemas en cargas los archivos .css, mi problema es cuando cargos los archivos .js que necesita el tema. La estructura del proyecto es la siguiente:

```
proyecto
   |
  ... 
   |
   +-> src
        |
        +-> assets
              |
              +-> css
              |
              +-> fonts
              |
              +-> img
              |
              +-> js
                  |
                  +-> app.config.js
                      app.js
   ...
```

El archivo `app.config.js` tiene un estructura interna como la siguiente:

```
$.root_ = $('body');
$.navAsAjax = false; 
$.sound_path = "sound/";
$.sound_on = true; 

var root = this,
    debugState = false, 
    debugStyle = 'font-weight: bold; color: #00f;',
    debugStyle_green = 'font-weight: bold; font-style:italic; color: #46C246;',
    debugStyle_red = 'font-weight: bold; color: #ed1c24;',
    debugStyle_warning = 'background-color:yellow',
    debugStyle_success = 'background-color:green; font-weight:bold; color:#fff;',
    debugStyle_error = 'background-color:#ed1c24; font-weight:bold; color:#fff;';
...
```

Y el archivo `app.js` tiene una estructura como ésta:

```
$.intervalArr = [];
var calc_navbar_height = function() {
        var height = null;

        if ($('#header').length)
            height = $('#header').height();

        if (height === null)
            height = $('<div id="header"></div>').height();

        if (height === null)
            return 49;
        // default
        return height;
    },

    navbar_height = calc_navbar_height,
    ...
    if (!ismobile) {
        // Desktop
        $.root_.addClass("desktop-detected");
        thisDevice = "desktop";
        return false; 
    } else {
        // Mobile
        $.root_.addClass("mobile-detected");
        thisDevice = "mobile";

        if (fastClick) {
            // Removes the tap delay in idevices
            // dependency: js/plugin/fastclick/fastclick.js 
            $.root_.addClass("needsclick");
            FastClick.attach(document.body); 
            return false; 
        }

    }
    ...
```

Como pueden ver, el archivo `app.js` utiliza variables declaradas en el archivo `app.config.js`, en el archivo main.js importo los achivos js de la siguiente manera

```
import '../assets/js/app.config.js'
import '../assets/js/app.js'
```

**El problema que estoy teniendo** es que el archivo `app.js` utiliza variables declaradas en el archivo `app.config.js` pero que no está reconociendo cuando los importo y me está produciendo errores `undefined`

No tengo problemas con JQuery ya que lo importa y lo reconoce bien, cualquier "luz" que me puedan dar será bien recibida

Comment: Tus archivos no están exportando nada. Pero, de todos modos, lo primero que debieras probar sería importar `app.config.js` desde `app.js` en vez de / adicionalmente a `main.js`

Comment: @amenadiel Entiendo eso, entonces los temas basados en Bootstrap no se pueden utilizar en Vue como se hace entonces en Angular donde no es necesario modificar nada en el tema para implementarlo? Igualmente voy hacer el intento importando `app.config.js` desde `app.js`